# echo $PATH giving different result to what .bash_profile states

Tags: homebrew

I'm trying to install Homebrew (to then install RVM, then Octopress).

Homebrew is installed but when I run `brew doctor` I get the message:

`Consider amending your PATH so that /usr/local/bin
occurs before /usr/bin in your PATH.`

I have changed my `~/.bash_profile` to `export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:$PATH"`.

`~/.bashrc` is empty.

`etc/paths` has

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

`echo $PATH` states 
`/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Users/deadlyhifi/.rvm/bin`

I tried installing RVM previously but had all kinds of problems with the compiler not being correct since I have Xcode 4.5.1 installed - I uninstalled RVM and am now trying again. My $PATH has reference to the RVM but I can't for the life in me find the file that contains that path.

Can anyone shed any light on the subject?

Edit:

The `etc/profile` contains:

```
# System-wide .profile for sh(1)

if [ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ]; then
eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`
fi

if [ "${BASH-no}" != "no" ]; then
[ -r /etc/bashrc ] && . /etc/bashrc
fi
```

Comment: Can you please copy and past your entire `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.profile`. Also, I assume that the paths in `\etc\paths` are not on the same line, right?

Comment: I've added the profile data, and etc/paths are on separate lines.

Comment: Please copy and paste also ~/.profile if exist

Comment: I've figured it out. I've got [Oh My ZSH](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh) installed. That's created `~/.zshrc`. This is where the $PATH is defined. I've edited that and now my system is raring to brew. I'd have never found that if I wasn't searching through all the `.files`.